# Segue from Tab View Controller to View Controller creating unexpected rectangular box at the top of the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I just finished implementing the SWRevealViewController class to allow for a slide-out menu to appear when the menuButton is pressed.

What it is supposed to look like (and did before implementing this feature):

[image: Intention]

What it now looks like:

[image: Outcome]

Here is what my Storyboard looks like:

[image: Storyboard]

How can I get this rectangular box to disappear?

Comment: Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Please help me understand what the problem is. :|

Comment: Anyone? I really need to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Open the Storyboard, select the Navigation Controller, open up the Attributes inspector, then select the drop-down menu for 'Top Bar' and choose "none."